# create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list, Django REST Framework (implementing my own create method error)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

when I am implementing this code-example on the documentation (I had to implement the create method myself because I have nested objects and inserting them is not supported by default)

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
    user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
    return user
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations

I'm getting this error

```
create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
```

My implementation of the example on my project is the following :

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    product_data = validated_data.pop('categories')
    product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
    Product.objects.create(product=product, **product_data)
    return product
```

the whole serializers.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from products_and_categories.models import Product, Category
from django.db import models


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        if 'categories' not in self.fields:
            self.fields['categories'] = CategorySerializer(obj, many=True)      
        return super(CategorySerializer, self).to_representation(obj)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ("name", 'products', 'categories')

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categories = CategorySerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ("product_code", "name", "quantity", "price", 'categories')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product_data = validated_data.pop('categories')
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Product.objects.create(product=product, **product_data)
        return product
```

my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categoriesId = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='categories',on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products')
```

can anybody help me figure out what's wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing various names here. You pop the `categories` element from `validated_data`, and assign it to `product_data`; but it is not product data, it is a list of categories.

You then try and create a Product with that data related to an existing product - presumably you meant to create a Category there. But again what you have is a *list*, so you need to iterate through and create one category per entry.

And finally note that you have a many-to-many relationship between product and category, not a foreign key as in the example, so you can't use that `product=product` syntax.

This would be better as:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    category_data = validated_data.pop('categories')
    product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for category in category_data:
        product.categories.create(**category)
    return product
```

(Although note that yes, creating nested items *is* supported by DRF; see the docs on [serializer relations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).)

Comment: Thanks so much, although after trying your way , I get an error saying `Direct assignment to the reverse side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use products.set() instead.` and when I used `product.categories.set(**category_data)`
I got `set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`

Comment: any idea what that is ?

Comment: This code wouldn't give that error. Can you update your question with the exact code you used?

Comment: you meant `category` by `category_data` in `product.categories.create(**category_data)`, right ? because otherwise it gives the `create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list` error again

Comment: I just assumed you meant `**category` instead of `**category_data`

Comment: okay , when I make that change I get that error `Direct assignment to the reverse side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use products.set() instead.`

Comment: Do you have any idea what that is for ?

Comment: But like I said, this code wouldn't give that error. You would get that if you did `product.categories = [category_list]`. But this code doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

So I'll add this answer in case you're a dummy like I am.

I had similar code to this working previously and made some changes to the Flask app's endpoint I was fetching the JSON from.

One of the changes I added was to add a `count` item to the dictionary so I could easily see how many items I was iterating.

So obviously when I went to save each model instance in Django based on this JSON data, the first item had an integer value for count, which is obviously not going to work.