# Django create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a writable nested serializer using DRF, I've been following the official documentation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

My use case is very similar to the one given in the documentation.

**models.py**

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['album', 'order']
        ordering = ['order']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%d: %s' % (self.order, self.title)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for track_data in tracks_data:
            Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
        return album
```

My view in which I'm passing my data(I'm doing some post processing and creating this data) to the serializer looks like below

NOTE: I'm creating this data in my view. *data* as per my understanding is a dictionary and 'tracks' has a list of dictionaries

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def my_view():
    ....
    my_data = 
    {
        'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
        'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
        'tracks': [
            {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
            {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
            {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
        ]
    }
    serializer = AlbumSerializer(data= my_data)
    serializer.is_valid()
    ....
```

Now every time I call **my_view** POST API, I get the following error

> **create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list**

My primary suspect is the format of *my_data* I believe, based on the error inside my_data, the 'tracks' should have a list of values as a map object maybe?

I've tried to follow some of the answers suggested in the stack overflow community

1. [Serialize multiple models and send all in one json response django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978045/serialize-multiple-models-and-send-all-in-one-json-response-django-rest-framewor)
2. [create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list, Django REST Framework (implementing my own create method error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418075/create-argument-after-must-be-a-mapping-not-list-django-rest-framework-i)

I've searched everywhere to understand what is going on but I couldn't, any leads on this would be very helpful, Thanks in advance!

**Update**

So I tried to verify if the data is valid by using

> python manager shell

The serializer.is_valid() is returning True, but I'm getting an error while saving the searializer

> TypeError: create() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list

Comment: `album = Album.objects.create(*validated_data)`?

Comment: show your models code

Comment: @bipll Thanks for replying, now it's throwing a new error 
create() takes 1 positional argument but 7 were given

Comment: @SuryaPratapRana I've updated my question

Comment: data = {
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': [
        {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
        {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
        {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
    ],
}

Comment: try to add comma after 'tracks': [
            {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
            {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
            {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
        ],

Comment: @SuryaPratapRana I tried adding a comma, I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding @property in my models.py

models.py

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def track_details(self):
        return self.track.all()

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album', related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['album', 'order']
        ordering = ['order']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%d: %s' % (self.order, self.title)
```

serializers.py

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for track_data in tracks_data:
            Track.objects.create(**track_data, album=album)
        return album
```